# Cocos2d sprite is drawn outside screen when transition

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

When I do page transition that shows the outside part of the stage (like CCTransitionFlipX), I can briefly see the sprites outside the screen while transition. It is really annoying. I thought I can manually check the position of the sprite in realtime and remove if it is off the screen. But that won't work if that sprite is partially outside.  Is there something like UIKit's clipSubviews in cocos2d?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [ClippingNode class](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/01/cocos2d-gem-clippingnode/) that might help.

Since the flip animation allows the user to see more than just the visible screen area, because the screen rotates, I think the behavior you observed may be expected.

Comment: I tried the ClippingNode class but it doesn't work as I expected. The clipping region doesn't get rotated as other elements in the transition. So I can still see the off-screen elements.